# System wants a manual fsck but has no (initramfs) prompt

Tags: boot

My laptop is asking for a manual fsck but there's an input/output error and there is no (initramfs) prompt so I can't write the fsck command. It just says unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually without   -a or -p and has no prompt.
How do I fix it?

Comment: You can and should run it from a live session. That said it's very likely the drive is beyond repair by software tools.

Comment: I'd start by checking out the health of your drive(s) - ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  I'd perform that check from *live* media first; then if the drive(s) are healthy; perform the `fsck` or file-system checks from *live* too.